# can I save models in this way in Django ?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
first_obj = MyFirstModel()
second_obj = ImageModel()

first_obj.name = "newname"
first_obj.phonenr = "9898876"

second_obj.image = "new image"

first_obj.save()

first_obj.create(second_obj) #<------ can i do this?
```

would this save the second object? is it ever possible to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to save a foreign key reference form the first to the second?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony, i am trying to save the second object by first object. they are in relation. YES to your comment

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony, there is a create function which will create and saves the related object, right?

Comment: No, you assign the second model to the FK attribute of the first model

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony, my problem is that i am looping thru xml file and gathering infos and save them to model at the end. the thing is, i have also an image object on the way, before i finish with collecting firstmodel infos,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting confused, try this:

```
class ImageModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()

class MyFirstModel(models.Model):
    name = ...
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)


> image_model_instance = ImageModel()
> image_model_instance.save()
> first_model_instance = MyFirstModel(name="foo")
> first_model_instance.image = image_model_instance
> first_model_instance.save()
```

There is a [`create()` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects), but it is used for creating and saving new instances of a model:

```
first_model_instance = MyFirstModel.objects.create(Name="foo")
```

so the same as:

```
first_model_instance = MyFirstModel()
first_model_instance.save()
```